# Is it possible to merge data from csv to mysql?

Tags: mysql

I've csv file that contains email + street address. I've wordpress installation with users that have same email and I'd like to import street addresses to respective users in user_meta table.

How can I do this?
One stupid way that comes to mind is to use text editor search and replace to create a huge list of insert queries.

Any better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
LOAD DATA INFILE your_file.csv
INTO your_table
```

References: [Load data - MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/es/load-data.html)